# In principal component regression, how to show that $X \beta_\mathrm{PCR}=U\: \mathrm{diag}\left\{1,\ldots, 1, 0, \ldots 0\right\}U^Ty$ if $X=USV^T$

Tags: regression, pca, svd

Regarding the third equation in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/133257/243601), I'm struggling to figure out how $ X \beta_\mathrm{PCR} =   U\: \mathrm{diag}\left\{1,\ldots, 1, 0, \ldots 0\right\} U^\top y$.

Given $X = USV^T$ where $X$ is $n \times p$, $S$ is a diagonal matrix, and $V$ is $p \times p$, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_regression#Details_of_the_method), $\beta_\mathrm{PCR}=V_k(V_k^TX^TXV_k)^{-1}V_k^TX^Ty$ where $V_k$ is $p\times k$ containing the first $k$ columns of $V$. I tried reducing $X\beta_{PCR}$ as follows:

\begin{align}
X\beta_\mathrm{PCR}=&USV^TV_k(V_k^TX^TXV_k)^{-1}V_k^TX^Ty\\
=&USV^TV_k(V_k^TVS^TU^TUSV^TV_k)^{-1}V_k^TVS^TU^Ty \\
=&USV^TV_k(V_k^TVS^2V^TV_k)^{-1}V_k^TVSU^Ty \\
\end{align}

I'm not sure how to reduce the above further to get the result from the posted answer, or specifically how to see that $SV^TV_k(V_k^TVS^2V^TV_k)^{-1}V_k^TVS$ is $\: \mathrm{diag}\left\{1,\ldots, 1, 0, \ldots 0\right\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since $V = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_p \end{bmatrix}$ is orthogonal, we have $v_i^Tv_j = \delta_{ij}$, whence
\begin{align}
& V_k^TV = \begin{bmatrix} v_1^T \\ v_2^T \\ \vdots \\ v_k^T \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & \cdots & v_p \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}I_{(k)} &  0 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times p}, \\
& V^TV_k = \begin{bmatrix} I_{(k)} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times k}
\end{align}

Given that $X$ is of full column rank, the $n \times p$ diagonal matrix $S$ has the form $S = \begin{bmatrix} \operatorname{diag}(s_1, \ldots, s_p) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.
Therefore (note that $S^TS \neq S^2$, because $S$ is not a square matrix! -- from here all is about block matrix multiplication operations, nothing particularly difficult),
\begin{align}
& V_k^TVS^TSV^TV_k = \begin{bmatrix} I_{(k)} & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\operatorname{diag}(s_1^2, \ldots, s_p^2)
\begin{bmatrix} I_{(k)} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \operatorname{diag}(s_1^2, \ldots, s_k^2), \\
& SV^TV_k = \begin{bmatrix} \operatorname{diag}(s_1, \ldots, s_p) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} I_{(k)} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} \operatorname{diag}(s_1, \ldots, s_k) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \\
& V_k^TVS^T =
\begin{bmatrix} \operatorname{diag}(s_1, \ldots, s_k) & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Plug these into $X\hat{\beta}_{\text{PCR}}$, we have
\begin{align}
 & USV^TV_k(V_k^TVS^TSV^TV_k)^{-1}V_k^TVS^TU^Ty \\
=& U\begin{bmatrix} \operatorname{diag}(s_1, \ldots, s_k) \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
\operatorname{diag}(s_1^{-2}, \ldots, s_k^{-2})
\begin{bmatrix} \operatorname{diag}(s_1, \ldots, s_k) & 0 \end{bmatrix}U^Ty \\
=& U\operatorname{diag}(I_{(k)}, 0)U^Ty. 
\end{align}