# Do I need to take out any predictors from multiple regression if I put in some principal components as additional predictors?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, pca, feature-selection

I have an assignment which involves one area-level dataset made of $366$ scale variables. I have to perform PCA, compare it with rates of an additional response variable $X$, and comment on its face validity.

I also have to do a regression analysis to predict rates of variable $X$.

I would like to be clever and add the PCA scores to the regression to see if it improves the predictive power of the model.

**Question:** I do not want to overestimate the predictive power of certain variables within the dataset. Do I have to exclude variables from the regression that are structurally related to the PCs that I put in? The PCA is very theory based and is done already, so I don't really want to mess with it.

Comment: "I would like to be clever" -- famous last words in statistics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It **does not make any sense** to add (any number of) principal components (PCs) to your $366$ predictors. This cannot possibly improve the quality of the model, because PCs are linear combinations of the original predictors and so by adding them you add nothing new. Instead, you make the regression degenerate, and quite likely will get an error from your software.

You **could in principle** add some PCs and remove some original variables, e.g. the ones that are most highly correlated with the PCs you are adding; this is an option that you are asking about. I would argue that this is very unlikely to make sense, because again, by adding PCs you do not add any new information, so should not expect the model to improve.

Somewhat paradoxically, it **can make a lot of sense** to remove the original predictors *altogether* and replace them by several (e.g. $5$ or $10$, but much less than $366$) PCs. This procedure even has a name! it is called *"principal components regression"* (PCR). Even though here, again, you do not add any new information, you remove a lot of predictors and will often end up removing a lot of useless predictors. Useless predictors tend to spoil your model (this is known as "overfitting"), and removing them can improve the model (this is known as "regularization"). You might want to read [this recent answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/127589/28666) for some further remarks on PCR and for some links to further discussions.

This is a subtle point, so take a moment to appreciate it: adding redundant information cannot improve the model, but removing useless information can.

Comment: I know I am a couple of years late responding to your answer, but it was indeed very useful. I am still using the last point in my studies. Thank you for replying

Comment: Hi @MissD, that's indeed nice to hear :-) Please consider "accepting" my answer by clicking on a green tick sign to the left of it. Once you have 15 reputation points, you will be able "upvote" my answer too by clicking on an upper arrow to the left of it. That's a way to say thank you here. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I hope to continue to use this great platform when I am less sleep deprived (new mother) and in work, so its good to know how to be as polite as I am in person :)

Comment: Congratulations, @MissD! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are cases when some of the original variables that were used in a PCA are no longer available (e.g. a follow-up of an old experiment or published sources not disclosing raw data). Leaving aside the question whether you should trust such (essentially unreproducible) data, let’s imagine you need to use *a certain* PC as a predictor of a newly collected response variable, alongside *a couple* of raw predictor variables, which may have been used in the original PCA.

In this case, you could check for correlations between individual variables and principal components you intend to use. If you had many, many raw variables, chances are that correlation of any one of them with a single PC is not very strong. But if you already had strong cross-correlations for variables going into PCA, you are likely to be overestimating them thrice.

As indicated by amoeba above and below, since PCs are linear combinations of the original variables, using all the PCs alongside all raw variables that went into a PC is a meaningless exercise. And if you still have all the original variables used in PCA, it makes much more sense to do what amoeba suggested in the comment above.

Comment: (-1) PCs are linear combinations of original variables. Adding them to the model should change *nothing* in the predictive power, because one is not adding independent predictors. Adding PCs without removing any original features is pointless and futile.

Comment: I'm surprised the regression runs at all without rank-deficient error.

Comment: @amoeba - You are correct if you add all PCs and all predictors. It is not the case if you add only one of the PCs and some of the original variables, though. I tried it with some of my data, using PC1 and 2 of 23 raw variables, both with unremarkable loadings on that PC. Predictive power of the model increased from 0.15 to 0.18. qed.

Comment: Yes, sure, but that is not what your last sentence says: *"adding [PCs as] extra variables will always improve ... the model"*. I will be happy to reverse my downvote if you make this clear. If you go as far as to mention principal components regression and explain what that is, I will even happily upvote :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice - I have taken it on board. Any word on the substantive model building question will be much appreciated and well received. Just for clarification I have reworded the question here: Now I have a PCA to add to my final model, should I discount variables that have a structural relationship to those included in the PCA, so as not to overestimate?

Comment: @MissD: my edited post hopefully answers the second part, but just to be clear - we are not talking about 'a PCA' to add (presumably meaning all PCs?), just one PC component of it; *all* raw variables will have a relationship with it, but some may not be very strong. I am not sure what's 'substantive model building' - a quick search gives an economics definition involving 'precise definition of incorporated concepts', if that's the case (?), yeah, by all means state what you are analyzing.

Comment: @amoeba - right, I clarified that in the edited version; extra vars just referred to MR, I removed that since it is confusing. I won't add pcr because (a) your linked answer does that quite well and (b) I was operating under the assumption PCs are "done already"/raw data unavailable, which I've now specified.

Comment: @katya, thanks, I removed my downvote. I am a bit confused though as to why you operate under the assumption that the raw data are (or might be) unavailable; the OP clearly states that the raw data are there and PCA is done as part of the exercise...

Comment: I can't get my head around even the starting point here. You're talking about situations where you don't have the original data, but you do have (the numerical values of) the PCs? In that situation, if it arises, how could you possibly know what you were using? How often does this arise? For that and other reasons already stated, this seems very strange advice and quite unsound in so far as I can follow it.